# Apache mod_deflate and zlib.output_compression

Tags: php, apache

Apache `mod_deflate` already enabled for my site, Can I enable `zlib.output_compression` in `PHP.INI`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you left `zlib.output_compression`, PHP files will use this compression and which is not that much efficient what much `mod_deflate` is. So Apache will compress all other files but not `PHP` and `zlib` will compress `PHP` files. No point in using them both.

If you are interesting is speeding up your `PHP` code you can always use `XCache` to keep PHP files pre-compiled.

Comment: you have cpanel right? try searching the web for cpanel+xcache or something like that.